# Issue with repeating sound in Xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, xcode, audio

When an frame hits another frame it plays a sound so i use this code in the did loader so the sound is loaded

i use the framework

`#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>`

`- (void)viewDidLoad`

```
 NSString *path1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ballbounce" ofType:@"mp3"];
theaudio1 = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path1] error: NULL];
```

then use this to play the sound

```
[audio1 play];
```

but some times the sound doesn't play, the sound clip is only 0.7 seconds long and just makes a simple noise.

like

```
enemy.center = CGPointMake(enemy.center.x+pos.x,enemy.center.y+pos.y);

    if (enemy.center.x > 308 || enemy.center.x < 10)

    {
        [theaudio1 play];
        pos.x = -pos.x;

    }
    if (enemy.center.y > 400 || enemy.center.y < 100)
    {
        [theaudio1 play];
        pos.y = -pos.y ;
    }
```

the sound sometimes plays in quick succession and sometimes the sound doesn't play is there a better way that i can write this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the `prepareToPlay` method on your `AVAudioPlayer` instance before you call `play`. It preloads the audio player's buffer.

Also, init your player to play from memory if you can, since it's only a very short sound. See the `initWithData:error` method description in the `AVAudioPlayer` class documentation.